# Wordpress site won't load, but dashboard side works fine?

Tags: wordpress

I've been working on this wordpress site for about a week now, and today when I went to work on it loaded fine in the browser.

I logged in and updated a few posts, went to look at the live site, and it just won't load.

The dashboard side is still loading fine, I can keep editing things, but the front end just won't load. Just sits and spins.

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening or what to try. Help!

http://danapaigetrentlage.com/cfsa-test/

Comment: seems to be loading fine for me!

Comment: Try clearing your cache, working fine for me too :)

Comment: Works for me..? Did you recently enable any plugins?

Comment: Very strange. I guess it's just me? I've tried multiple computers in my house; all with the same result. Must be my connection or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what the problem is, but it seems to be related to the internet connection at my house. I tethered my phone to my computer and was able to load the page no problem.

Thanks for the responses and comments, it helped me diagnose my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this for me...

[image]

So although it loads, the navigation is messed up. I think this is due to your HTML tags not matching up. You need to close something somewhere in the navigation list. Maybe that has something to do with your loading issue.